# Which Design pattern to choose for this requirement?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a requirement, where assume, I will get a file from the client in one language and need to transform it to the other language. Assume that I will get all the details from the client namely, the file name, current language of the file, language to which the file needs to be transformed and the output file name.

What I need to do is to 
a) First, when the client invokes the application, the application will list all the language conversions that the application currently supports
b) Get all the details from the client for the conversion
c) Return the client the output file (assume this happens synchronously and the client will wait until is done).

I need to design in such a way that 
a) in the future, my application should support more languages, so in such case there should be minimal change to the existing code
b) so, each time if the application supports a new language conversion, then that need to listed when the client invokes this application
b) So, assume that currently the application invokes an API 'xyz' for the conversion and to support more language conversions let's assume that we have found a new API 'abc' then we need to utilize the new API with minimal change to the existing code.

Please let me know if the above requirements can be satisfied by a single pattern or by a combination of patterns.

Comment: How are you going to do the conversion?  You do realize that automatic language translation tools are not very accurate.

Comment: For the actual translation's I think the strategy pattern would fit apart from that I suppose any mvc type architectural pattern for the actual application interface

Comment: @Mystere Man, assume that we have a perfect language translation API available.. I am more concerned on the design pattern or the design approach where I will be needed to make less change in the existing code, in case if I switch to a new language translation API (may be a better one than the current).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that language conversions generally use a similar algorithm the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) could be helpful to you.